# How can I change the color of the counter on a button?

Tags: javascript, html, button, colors

I need help changing the color of the number counter on a button, is there any way to do this? A website offers a free code for a set of reaction buttons but the number counter color they have set for default is grey and I'm trying to make it stand out more so I'm trying to change it to white. I reached out to them and asked if they had an option for customization on the color of the counter and they told me they don't have that option at the moment so I'm trying to see if there's a way to enter some code to get that white color on the counter.

I don't have access to the css style tags, just the HTML code I have provided below. Which probably makes this that much harder or impossible. Just seeing if anyone knows a method to achieve this.

I'll paste the code below, but I don't think it will render just use the photo as visual reference.

Take a look and see if you can help,

Thank you.

```html
<div class="sharethis-inline-reaction-buttons"></div>
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you using the plugin? If you have access to any CSS at all you should be able to add styles to the classes used in the plugin.

Try doing

```
.st-count {
    color: white !important;
}
```

Add that anywhere that will load on the same page. If you have access to a CSS file that loads on that page, add it there. If you have access to the HTML of the page, add a `<style></style>` tag and add it in there. If you're using this in Wordpress, you could even add it to the CSS of your theme so long as it is in a place that will load at the same time as your plugin.

I've tried this on another page using the same plugin and it does work.

It is generally bad practice to use the `!important` tag, but if you don't have more direct access to the CSS then there isn't anything else you can do. Just using `color: white` won't work because the plugin will override it.

Comment: This worked! I put my code in the custom HTML and put your code into the CSS on my page builder for that specific page, and this did the trick. Thank you Michael.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a style color attribute of white to the tag. This is usually done in the css style tags, but it depends what you have access to. I've given a background color too, just so that you can see it:

```html
<div class="sharethis-inline-reaction-buttons" style="background:rgba(0,0,0,0.9); color:white;">0 1 2 3 4 5</div>
```

Comment: I don't have access to the css style tags, I only have access to the code I provided. I went ahead and tried this method and it didn't work. Thanks for you input.

Comment: I can also corroborate that doing this, even if you add `!important`, won't work for this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your css. Change the color to anything you would like. The .st-count class is what controls the styling of the numbers.

```
.st-count{
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: I don't have access to the css style tags, I only have access to the html code I provided. Thanks for you input.